# Why does yaw return weird values after tilting on a different axis?

Tags: imu, mpu

I have an [*MPU9250*](https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/PS-MPU-9250A-01-v1.1.pdf) on my board and I wanted to change the *yaw* calculating axis after reboot depending on how this board is placed, like this:

[image]

So now i can rotate the *yaw* counting axis, thanks to the answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/596954/why-doesnt-yaw-calculating-axis-change-after-board-reboot). In the image below you can see board' deafult position and new position:

[image]

And swapped some values that are passing to *Madgwick* filter depending on the image:
[image]

```c
void Process_IMU()
{
    //read raw data
    uint8_t data[14];
    uint8_t reg = ACCEL_XOUT_H;
    uint8_t mpu_address = MPU9250_ADDRESS_DEFAULT;


    while(HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(_MPU9250_I2C,(uint16_t)mpu_address,&reg,1,1000) != HAL_OK);
    while(HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(_MPU9250_I2C, (uint16_t)mpu_address, data, 14, 1000) != HAL_OK);

    /*-------- Accel ---------*/
    Accel_x = (int16_t)((int16_t)( data[0] << 8 ) | data[1]);
    Accel_y = (int16_t)((int16_t)( data[2] << 8 ) | data[3]);
    Accel_z = (int16_t)((int16_t)( data[4] << 8 ) | data[5]);

    /*-------- Gyrometer --------*/
    Gyro_x = (int16_t)((int16_t)( data[8] << 8  ) | data[9]);
    Gyro_y = (int16_t)((int16_t)( data[10] << 8 ) | data[11]);
    Gyro_z = (int16_t)((int16_t)( data[12] << 8 ) | data[13]);


    Accel_X = 10*(float)((int32_t)Accel_x - Accel_x_bias)/(float)accel_sensitivity;
    Accel_Y = 10*(float)((int32_t)Accel_y - Accel_y_bias)/(float)accel_sensitivity;
    Accel_Z =  10*(float)((int32_t)Accel_z - Accel_z_bias)/(float)accel_sensitivity ;

    Gyro_X =  (float)(((int32_t)Gyro_x - Gyro_x_bias)/(float)gyro_sensitivity)*M_PI/180.0f;
    Gyro_Y =  (float)(((int32_t)Gyro_y - Gyro_y_bias)/(float)gyro_sensitivity)*M_PI/180.0f;
    Gyro_Z =  (float)(((int32_t)Gyro_z - Gyro_z_bias)/(float)gyro_sensitivity)*M_PI/180.0f;

    // Get data of Magnetometer
    // Get_magnetometer();

//   for default placement
//   MadgwickAHRSupdateIMU(Gyro_X,Gyro_Y,Gyro_Z,Accel_X,Accel_Y,Accel_Z);
//   for new placement
     MadgwickAHRSupdateIMU(-Gyro_Z,Gyro_Y,-Gyro_X,Accel_Z,Accel_Y,-Accel_X);
}
```

And here is the *MadgwickAHRSupdateIMU():*

```c
void MadgwickAHRSupdateIMU(float gx, float gy, float gz, float ax, float ay, float az) {
    float recipNorm;
    float s0, s1, s2, s3;
    float qDot1, qDot2, qDot3, qDot4;
    float _2q0, _2q1, _2q2, _2q3, _4q0, _4q1, _4q2 ,_8q1, _8q2, q0q0, q1q1, q2q2, q3q3;

    // Rate of change of quaternion from gyroscope
    qDot1 = 0.5f * (-q1 * gx - q2 * gy - q3 * gz);
    qDot2 = 0.5f * (q0 * gx + q2 * gz - q3 * gy);
    qDot3 = 0.5f * (q0 * gy - q1 * gz + q3 * gx);
    qDot4 = 0.5f * (q0 * gz + q1 * gy - q2 * gx);

    // Compute feedback only if accelerometer measurement valid (avoids NaN in accelerometer normalisation)
    if(!((ax == 0.0f) && (ay == 0.0f) && (az == 0.0f))) {

        // Normalise accelerometer measurement
        recipNorm = invSqrt(ax * ax + ay * ay + az * az);
        ax *= recipNorm;
        ay *= recipNorm;
        az *= recipNorm;

        // Auxiliary variables to avoid repeated arithmetic
        _2q0 = 2.0f * q0;
        _2q1 = 2.0f * q1;
        _2q2 = 2.0f * q2;
        _2q3 = 2.0f * q3;
        _4q0 = 4.0f * q0;
        _4q1 = 4.0f * q1;
        _4q2 = 4.0f * q2;
        _8q1 = 8.0f * q1;
        _8q2 = 8.0f * q2;
        q0q0 = q0 * q0;
        q1q1 = q1 * q1;
        q2q2 = q2 * q2;
        q3q3 = q3 * q3;

        // Gradient decent algorithm corrective step
        s0 = _4q0 * q2q2 + _2q2 * ax + _4q0 * q1q1 - _2q1 * ay;
        s1 = _4q1 * q3q3 - _2q3 * ax + 4.0f * q0q0 * q1 - _2q0 * ay - _4q1 + _8q1 * q1q1 + _8q1 * q2q2 + _4q1 * az;
        s2 = 4.0f * q0q0 * q2 + _2q0 * ax + _4q2 * q3q3 - _2q3 * ay - _4q2 + _8q2 * q1q1 + _8q2 * q2q2 + _4q2 * az;
        s3 = 4.0f * q1q1 * q3 - _2q1 * ax + 4.0f * q2q2 * q3 - _2q2 * ay;
        recipNorm = invSqrt(s0 * s0 + s1 * s1 + s2 * s2 + s3 * s3); // normalise step magnitude
        s0 *= recipNorm;
        s1 *= recipNorm;
        s2 *= recipNorm;
        s3 *= recipNorm;

        // Apply feedback step
        qDot1 -= beta * s0;
        qDot2 -= beta * s1;
        qDot3 -= beta * s2;
        qDot4 -= beta * s3;
    }

    // Integrate rate of change of quaternion to yield quaternion
    q0 += qDot1 * (1.0f / sampleFreq);
    q1 += qDot2 * (1.0f / sampleFreq);
    q2 += qDot3 * (1.0f / sampleFreq);
    q3 += qDot4 * (1.0f / sampleFreq);

    // Normalise quaternion
    recipNorm = invSqrt(q0 * q0 + q1 * q1 + q2 * q2 + q3 * q3);
    q0 *= recipNorm;
    q1 *= recipNorm;
    q2 *= recipNorm;
    q3 *= recipNorm;
}
```

Here is how I calculate φ, θ, ψ in *main.c* loop:

```c
Process_IMU();

q[0] = q0;
q[1] = q1;
q[2] = q2;
q[3] = q3;
a12 =   2.0f * (q[1] * q[2] + q[0] * q[3]);
a22 =   q[0] * q[0] + q[1] * q[1] - q[2] * q[2] - q[3] * q[3];
a31 =   2.0f * (q[0] * q[1] + q[2] * q[3]);
a32 =   2.0f * (q[1] * q[3] - q[0] * q[2]);
a33 =   q[0] * q[0] - q[1] * q[1] - q[2] * q[2] + q[3] * q[3];
float sinp = a32;
if (abs(sinp) >= 1)
    pitch = copysign(M_PI/2,sinp);
else
    pitch = asin(sinp);
//pitch = -asinf(a32);
roll  = atan2f(a31, a33);
yaw   = atan2f(a12, a22) * 2;
pitch *= 180.0f / pi;
yaw = atan2f(sinf(yaw),cosf(yaw));
yaw   *= 180.0f / pi;
roll  *= 180.0f / pi;
```

So when I unload the program, everything work well and *yaw* is calculating as I expected:
[image]

Until the moment when I slightly tilt the board along one of the axes and return it to its previous position:
[image]

And after that when I try to rotate it around *yaw* axis (as I rotated before) it returns me very weird values. Even when I do not rotate the board it gives me the "noise":
[image]

What could be the reason of this? Thanks for any advice!

**EDIT 1:** I have checked out Accel and Gyro values and it seems, that they are correct:
[image]
I think that conversions are correct.
**EDIT 2:** I found where is the problem, but I don't know why doesn't it work as should. The problematic line is `recipNorm = invSqrt(s0 * s0 + s1 * s1 + s2 * s2 + s3 * s3);`. `recipNorm` starts from 0 and goes up to 500 and then `recipNorm` is very randomatic. I thought that problem is in `invSqrt` but I found somewhere stable `invSqrt` code:

```c
int instability_fix = 1;

float invSqrt(float x) {
    if (instability_fix == 0)
    {
        /* original code */
        float halfx = 0.5f * x;
        float y = x;
        long i = *(long*)&y;
        i = 0x5f3759df - (i>>1);
        y = *(float*)&i;
        y = y * (1.5f - (halfx * y * y));
        return y;
    }
    else if (instability_fix == 1)
    {
        /* close-to-optimal  method with low cost from http://pizer.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/fast-inverse-square-root */
        unsigned int i = 0x5F1F1412 - (*(unsigned int*)&x >> 1);
        float tmp = *(float*)&i;
        return tmp * (1.69000231f - 0.714158168f * x * tmp * tmp);
    }
    else
    {
        /* optimal but expensive method: */
        return 1.0f / sqrtf(x);
    }
}
```

But I tested all of them and they work similary. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Noise can appear from improper type conversions or MSB/LSB swapping, however your code does look good. I recommend printing out (if possible) the immediate value of the Accel (one axis is fine) to see if conversions could be the issue, before doing the additional processing. Sometimes positive values will look good, then negative values shows up as noise.

Comment: @icodeplenty Thanks for reply! I have checked Accel and Gyro values and they are correct when negative or positive. Maybe there could be an issue in ```MadgwickAHRSupdateIMU```?